# JavaScript Animation Dynamically Return Location on Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to delve into the intricacies of animation in JavaScript and have a few functional questions. In my code, I'm trying to "launch" a "rocket" after pressing a "button". I've noticed that once I start my function, my values calculate how I want them to but the position of the rocket on the webpage does not change until the function returns.

So onto my questions:

Is there any way to dynamically update the location (rocket.style.top) of the rocket while inside my function? If not, what would be a better way to go about updating the location? Should I use something other than an event listener on a button?

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.button');
var rocket = document.querySelector('.rocket');
var x = rocket.offsetTop;
var a = 1;

function launch() {
  while (a < 1000) {
    console.log(x);
    console.log(a);
    console.log(rocket.style.top);
    rocket.style.top = x - a + 'px';
    a += a;
    sleep(1000);
  }
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', launch);
```

```css
div.button {
  font-family: impact;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 25px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.rocket {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='button'>launch</div>
  <div class='rocket'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this using jquery:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

$('.button').click(async function() {
  var a = 0;
  var x = 10;
  while (a < 50) {
    var upd = String(x-a) + 'px';
    $('.rocket').css("margin-bottom", upd);
    a += -x;
    await sleep(50);
  }
});
```

```css
div.button {
  font-family: impact;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 25px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.rocket {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='button'>launch</div>
  <div class='rocket'></div>
</body>

</html>
```